# Can I declare array using loop?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array declaration:

```
adminExam.detailTabInputData1 = [
   { id: 'examName', keys: 'Test Exam 1' },
   { id: 'published', keys: '2014-06-27' },
   { id: 'price', keys: '100' }
]
```

I would like to create let say 10 to 100 versions of this with slight changes just like the following:

```
// New data 2
adminExam.detailTabInputData2 = [
   { id: 'examName', keys: 'Test Exam 2' },
   { id: 'published', keys: '2014-06-29' },
   { id: 'price', keys: '200' },
]
```

Is it possible to do this using a function or a loop?

Comment: Yes, but you should really use an array to store them instead of manually adding numbers to the object member name.

Comment: If you tell us how the "slight changes" are done, we might even be able to help you with the code.

Comment: Well i would rather suggest to create an array which which will store data in Key-Value pair. Each time you iterate through loop then you can add new entry to your array which will have a key which you want and an array as a value of that... This way you can create as many as versions of it without much hassel

Comment: Why it is been marked Negative !!!

Comment: @KD because she posted a question without showing minimal efforts. That's so simply

Comment: Come on girls! Nobody has a solution? That's just simple `for` loop

Comment: Its next to imposible without knowing how each one is different, if each array has an extra 1 in each part, then its easy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're building on an object we can use the square bracket notation "[]" to make dynamically named properties on that object. In this instance square bracket notation "[]" and dot notation "." are interchangeable.

For example: `adminExam['detailTabInputData1']` and `adminExam.detailTabInputData1` pull the same object property. But since square bracket notation uses a string property name we can concatenate a variable into it to form property names on the fly.

```
var adminExam = {}; // instantiate object
// source of data used to form dynamic object properties
var data = [[1, '2014-06-27', '100'], [2, '2014-06-29', '200'], [3, '2014-07-07', '300']];

// loop over data to build new, dynamic object properties
for ( var ii = 0, dataLen = data.length; ii < dataLen; ii++ ) {
    // concatenate first element of current data row into property name
    adminExam['detailTabInputData' + data[ii][0]] = [
        { id: 'examName', keys: 'Test Exam ' + data[ii][0] },
        { id: 'published', keys: data[ii][1] },
        { id: 'price', keys: data[ii][2] }
    ];
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/uf9Kd/ (Be sure to open your browser javascript console to view objects and properties.)

Comment: Comment your code, that helps for newbies. Comment at least basic stuff

Comment: Thanks @bloodyKnucles for the comment. It is not exactly what I was looking for but it gave me an idea. And sorry if my question wasn't clear. Obviously I am a newbie. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this. It is a little awkward with the lack of specs provided but I will try my best.

I would normally approach this from the perspective of establishing small functions that do just one thing. You mentioned you wanted slight variations in data so I'd tackle that first:

```
function rand(variance) {
  return Math.floor(Math.rand() * variance);
}

var baseDate = new Date();
function variableDate(seed) {
  var base = new Date(baseDate);
  base.setDate(base.getDate() + seed + rand(5));
  return base;
}

var basePrice = 100;
function price(seed) {
  return basePrice + seed;
}

var baseExamId = 1;
function examName(seed) {
  return 'Test Exam ' + (baseExamId + seed);
}
```

Plug in in those Lego pieces we can make a factory method:

```
function createItem(id, key) {
  // It is unclear why this data structure and property names were choosen.
  return { id: id, keys: key };
}

function createEntry(seed) {
  // Again it is unclear why an array was choosen over an object in this case.
  return [
    createItem('examName',  examName(seed)),
    createItem('published', variableDate(seed)),
    createItem('price',     price(seed))
  ];
}
```

Now finally we loop through and assign the new values to a continer object.

```
function createAdminExam(size) {
  var i, data = {};
  for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    data['detailTabInputData' + i] = createEntry(i);
  }
  return data;
}

var adminExam = createAdminExam(10);
```

There are a lot more effective ways to accomplish this kind of logic. Most of
the confusion comes from the choice of the data structure. As an exercise to
the reader, try to think of ways this could have been approached differently
and what alternative data structures could have been used to help in readability
and/or performance.